# Tensorflow Executor failed to create kernel. Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

I'm trying to build a custom CNN classifier for a load of cancer images (.png) using Tensorflow 1.1.0 and TFLearn 0.3.1 by largely following someone else's CNN classifier [here](https://medium.com/@husseinjaafar/my-first-cnn-in-tflearn-1019f88485f3), however when I try to fit my model Tensorflow is throwing out the following errors:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:983] Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:594] Executor failed to create kernel. Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported
     [[Node: Adam/apply_grad_op_0/update_FullyConnected_1/b/Cast_2 = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_STRING, _class=["loc:@FullyConnected_1/b"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Adam/apply_grad_op_0/learning_rate)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:983] Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:594] Executor failed to create kernel. Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported
     [[Node: Adam/apply_grad_op_0/update_FullyConnected_1/b/Cast_2 = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_STRING, _class=["loc:@FullyConnected_1/b"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Adam/apply_grad_op_0/learning_rate)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:983] Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:594] Executor failed to create kernel. Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported
     [[Node: Adam/apply_grad_op_0/update_conv_1/W/Cast_2 = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_STRING, _class=["loc:@conv_1/W"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Adam/apply_grad_op_0/learning_rate)]]
```

I am using tflearn.data_utils.image_preloader to read the png files in however I have also tried using a few other approaches but seem to always get the same error back.  A lot of research has suggested this may be due to bad image files however I get the same issue after wget'ing a dozen jpg images, so it has to be something else.  Any advice would be appreciated, my code is below, with the larger project at my git [here](https://github.com/jhole89/classifying-cancer/tree/feature/tflearn/cnn_image_classifier)

```
import numpy as np
import tflearn
from tflearn.data_preprocessing import ImagePreprocessing
from tflearn.data_utils import image_preloader
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, fully_connected, dropout
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression


def train():

    training_path = 'images/train'

    image_height = 32
    image_width = 32
    colour_channels = 3

    X, Y = image_preloader(
        training_path,
        image_shape=(image_height, image_width),
        mode='folder',
        categorical_labels=True,
        normalize=True)

    X = np.reshape(X, (-1, image_height, image_width, colour_channels))

    img_prep = ImagePreprocessing()
    img_prep.add_featurewise_zero_center()
    img_prep.add_featurewise_stdnorm()

    network = input_data(shape=[None, image_height, image_width, colour_channels],
                         data_preprocessing=img_prep,
                         name='input')

    network = conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu', name='conv_1')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
    network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu', name='conv_2')
    network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu', name='conv_3')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
    network = fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 2, activation='softmax')

    network = regression(
        network,
        optimizer='adam',
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        learning_rate='0.001')

    model = tflearn.DNN(
        network,
        checkpoint_path='tmp/tflearn/cnn/checkpoints/model.tflearn',
        tensorboard_verbose=3,
        tensorboard_dir='tmp/tflearn/cnn/logs/')

    model.fit(
        X, Y,
        validation_set=0.2,
        n_epoch=1000,
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=100,
        run_id='model',
        snapshot_epoch=True)

    model.save('tmp/tflearn/cnn/model/model_final.tflearn')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late answer (might help others)

I had the same problem and the problem is in your code for regression u have written

```
learning_rate='0.001'
```

But the learning rate is a `float` value not a `string` so just write :

```
learning_rate = 0.001
```

It will work

Comment: equally sorry for the late acceptance.  I ended up ditching tflearn as it was just too unstable at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Also responding for future viewers. I had the same issue but it was using Keras, with `model = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()` and `model.fit`.
My problem was that I used `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe` where the dataframe was created by reading a CSV, and the values were not of the right type. This fixed it:

```
TrainData['filename'] = TrainData['filename'].astype(dtype='string')
TrainData['class'] = TrainData['class'].astype(dtype='float')
```